# Do I need to use a horizontal layout (android studio 1.5.1)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in the Android world and I have a little problem with the screen in horizontal position. My android studio version is 1.5.1.
I have already completed the vertical layout, but I have issues when I turn the mobile in horizontal position; all the images, buttons get moving and the VideoView disappears. 
This how my layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ubuntunyx.apptest3.MainActivity"
android:background="#a987b7"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#4c335a"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/LytRelVideoResize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_weight="0.94">

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnResize"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/btnResize"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:onClick="btnResize_click"
android:background="@drawable/btn_redondo"
android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgResize"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgResize"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgResize"
android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="41dp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgResize"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ocaso"
android:layout_below="@+id/barResize"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="49dp" />

<VideoView
android:id="@+id/videoPiramides"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_below="@+id/imgResize"
android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/barResize"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/barResize"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnResize"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnResize" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgDragDrop"
android:layout_width="118dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:src="@drawable/buho"
android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnExit"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="81dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/btnExit"
android:onClick="btnExit_click"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="#124a68"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I was looking at: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html but it just get me more confused.

Comment: one issue with your layout is that you are referring a `"@+id/barResize"` in your alignements, but you don't have a view that has this id

Comment: That's because I delete the seekbar and I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need  to build another layout landscape
just follow the picture below:

[image: click No.1 the No. 2 and will see No. 3 layout with your <code>layoutName.xml</code>(land)]

and then you design that new layout as you wish.

OR
if you dont need that landscape (forcing the APP to set in one orientation only)

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

and add this one of these code to the application tag

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is to create design for landscape mode. You should make new folder called 'layout-land' in your res folder. In new folder create new layout file with the same name but with design for landscape mode. Android os will know when to use landscape and when to use portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here:
1. Rearrange the layout child views so that they look fine both in landscape and portrait mode. This will need trial and error and is not always possible.
2. Make your activity stick to a particular layout, regardless of changes in the device orientation. This can be done in you apps manifest file as:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

3.**The best way:** Create separate layout files for landscape and portrait orientations. In android studio it is easy. Suppose you have an activity named MyActivity, then the layout files will be something like: `my_activity.xml` (for normal, portrait mode) and `my_activity_land.xml` for landscape mode.